# How can I set the distance between repeated textures?

Tags: uv, node-editor

[image]

In the extension settings mainly you choose repeat, right? But can you change the distance between that repeat texture without stretching or adding more geometry lines? Using nodes maybe?

Comment: There has to be a color in the "space" between textures so why not just ad a rimm of that color around the texture in the image file? (Transparency is also posssible using an alpha channel)

Comment: @vklidu: Robin will come in 5 mins with the perfect nodegroup and just need 2 nodes to create it ;) but i don't think the brick texture will help, because it doesn't output vectors....but i am curious. maybe Robins finds a way...

Comment: But i think, it is also a good use case for python ;) So Batfinger is in the game ;)

Comment: @Chris Brick texture node is commonly used UV shift (like for a plank floor) ... Just plug node between Texture coordinates and Image node to see a magic ... :)

Comment: @vklidu: ok, now the brick texture makes sense ;) buuuut it cannot do what OP wants...isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

Using default plane unwrapping the plane will be mapped 1:1 to the texture, so I multiply the coordinates so they go outside the boundaries. Then I apply modulo, to get a repeating 0..x range, where x is the the value in modulo node. To get spacing, use modulo > 1 to get some values outside the texture, and of course set *"repeat"* mode to *"clip"*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was easy. Now i learnt that too ;) Great solution!

Comment: Awesome ... pure frustration :) sometimes I feel like from a different planet.

Comment: @vklidu: nope, you aren't. They are....!!!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by this (I didn't complete it, because I was too lazy):

[image]

But you would have to copy the mapping + image node and mix node for every tile you need and adapt the x/y coordinate accordingly. Of course, you could also make a node group from this to make it easier to use and reduce some nodes. But [Filip's suggestion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227355/how-to-set-distance-between-repeated-texture/227384#comment383530_227355) is quicker...except you need this for hundreds of pictures. Then mine might be reasonable.

If it wasn't clear what I meant, here is the node tree for three tiles:

[image]

Comment: I'm considering downvoting you for laziness. :)

Comment: NIKEEEEEEE -just do it!!! I deserve it!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady buuuuut, with my solution I helped people to help themselves because they don‘t just copy it and it works but they have to think themselves and then really understand the solution. So maybe it is even better than a ready made solution 