# Constructing tiles

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

first of all, I am relative new to blender, I am working through a book architecture with blender, and now I am able to construct walls, doors and windows. Was not easy to achieve.
Now I discovered how to use materials and load images to these materials. With this knowledge I am trying to construct tiles for my bathroom. I have a photo of the tiles I would like to place on the surface and between the tiles white small spaces.
How would you recommend me to proceed ? Make a big white plane and subtract with a logic operation the tiles from it, so there remains a kind of web for the white space between the tiles ? Or Construct a file having a white border around it ?
Since the tiles I took the photo do not have a regular color, I generated a dozen of different parts of this original tile in order to avoid having the exact same tile. Maybe better generate to wall using scripting ?
Thx a lot for any advice. I hope to understand your answers, I repeat I am real a beginner in this nice word of blender.
Again thx a lot
Yours,
Eryk

---

[image]

This is the image of the tile I have. I would like to construct of this tile the whole wall including the white gaps between the tiles.

Comment: Unless you have a pressing need to do tiles in geometry, I would do it as a texture. Look at the procedural brick texture. Can you share a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you're asking - as Ron mentioned, pictures help. If you mean you already have gaps between the tiles, but want them textured differently that the surface of the tiles, you don't have to make the "gaps" a new object, you can simply select the faces and assign a different material (one mesh can have multiple materials). If you need something else instead, it would be helpful if you could clarify a bit more about your setup., so we can help you more easily.

Comment: Thx a lot. I do not remember how do attach images ....   sorry. I have a photo of the tiles and I would like to put tiles on the wall using the image of this tile. I do not have gaps between the tiles, I need them, how in a bathroom tiles are laid down.

Comment: oops, pressed to soon enter, excuse me ....  now I try to understand how to attach pictures, ...  then it will be clearer ...  thank you very much

Comment: For adding spacing between the tiles (grout): [How can I set the distance between repeated textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227355/how-can-i-set-the-distance-between-repeated-textures/227390#227390)